# How to redirect a controller action to an action in module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes, action

I have a update action declared in `concerns/college.rb` which is a module.
I have a controller named `Forms` which has action `basic_form`. This action displays the form. But when this form is filled, I want it to go to update action in the module.

I have my routes file as :

```
    resource :form, , only: [:update] do
      get :basic_form
    end
```

After the form is filled from the front end, I want it to go to the update action in the module. How can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: possible code error: " :form,  , only: " too many commas there :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have included the module in controller, then def update is also the action/method of the **Forms controller**.

You can redirect from one action to another action as below

```
class FormsController < ApplicationController
  include college

  def basic_form
     redirect_to action: :update
  end

end
```

Please refer for more details. [ActionController::Redirecting](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to)

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hey I tried the given solution but it gives error as 'ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "app/forms"): ' This could be because the action basic form is declared to 'get' .

Comment: You need to update routes and also need to pass the params in redirect_to part, if you are updating the object or performing some operation.